# Can't start SpringBoot App in IntellijIdea

Tags: spring-boot

Coding a small SpringBott starter.  I have a problem configuring Spring Boot profile.

My git:  https://github.com/anatoliy19/3.1.1..git

```
C:\Users\admin\.jdks\openjdk-18.0.1.1\bin\java.exe -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dspring.jmx.enabled=true -Dspring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain -Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=63246:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\java\3.1.1\target\classes;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa\2.7.0\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.7.0.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-aop\2.7.0\spring-boot-starter-aop-2.7.0.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.9.7\aspectjweaver-1.9.7.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-jdbc\2.7.0\spring-boot-starter-jdbc-2.7.0.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\com\zaxxer\HikariCP\4.0.3\HikariCP-4.0.3.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\jakarta\transaction\jakarta.transaction-api\1.3.3\jakarta.transaction-api-1.3.3.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\jakarta\persistence\jakarta.persistence-api\2.2.3\jakarta.persistence-api-2.2.3.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aspects\5.3.20\spring-aspects-5.3.20.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf\2.7.0\spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf-2.7.0.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\2.7.0\spring-boot-starter-2.7.0.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\2.7.0\spring-boot-2.7.0.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\2.7.0\spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.0.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\2.7.0\spring-boot-starter-logging-2.7.0.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.2.11\logback-classic-1.2.11.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.2.11\logback-core-1.2.11.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.17.2\log4j-to-slf4j-2.17.2.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.17.2\log4j-api-2.17.2.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.36\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.36.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\jakarta\annotation\jakarta.annotation-api\1.3.5\jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.30\snakeyaml-1.30.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\org\thymeleaf\extras\thymeleaf-extras-java8time\3.0.4.RELEASE\thymeleaf-extras-java8time-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-validation\2.7.0\spring-boot-starter-validation-2.7.0.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-el\9.0.63\tomcat-embed-el-9.0.63.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\validator\hibernate-validator\6.2.3.Final\hibernate-validator-6.2.3.Final.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\jakarta\validation\jakarta.validation-api\2.0.2\jakarta.validation-api-2.0.2.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web\2.7.0\spring-boot-starter-web-2.7.0.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-json\2.7.0\spring-boot-starter-json-2.7.0.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.13.3\jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.13.3\jackson-annotations-2.13.3.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.13.3\jackson-core-2.13.3.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.13.3\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.13.3.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.13.3\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.13.3.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.13.3\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.13.3.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-tomcat\2.7.0\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.7.0.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-core\9.0.63\tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\9.0.63\tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.63.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\5.3.20\spring-web-5.3.20.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\jakarta\xml\bind\jakarta.xml.bind-api\2.3.3\jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.3.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\jakarta\activation\jakarta.activation-api\1.2.2\jakarta.activation-api-1.2.2.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\5.3.20\spring-core-5.3.20.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\5.3.20\spring-jcl-5.3.20.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-maven-plugin\2.7.0\spring-boot-maven-plugin-2.7.0.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-buildpack-platform\2.7.0\spring-boot-buildpack-platform-2.7.0.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\net\java\dev\jna\jna-platform\5.7.0\jna-platform-5.7.0.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\net\java\dev\jna\jna\5.7.0\jna-5.7.0.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-compress\1.21\commons-compress-1.21.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpclient\4.5.13\httpclient-4.5.13.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.4.15\httpcore-4.4.15.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.15\commons-codec-1.15.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\org\tomlj\tomlj\1.0.0\tomlj-1.0.0.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\org\antlr\antlr4-runtime\4.7.2\antlr4-runtime-4.7.2.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\com\google\code\findbugs\jsr305\3.0.2\jsr305-3.0.2.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-loader-tools\2.7.0\spring-boot-loader-tools-2.7.0.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\org\sonatype\plexus\plexus-build-api\0.0.7\plexus-build-api-0.0.7.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\plexus\plexus-utils\1.5.8\plexus-utils-1.5.8.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\5.6.5.Final\hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.4.3.Final\jboss-logging-3.4.3.Final.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\javax\persistence\javax.persistence-api\2.2\javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.12.10\byte-buddy-1.12.10.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\antlr\antlr\2.7.7\antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\transaction\jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec\1.1.1.Final\jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.1.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\org\jboss\jandex\2.4.2.Final\jandex-2.4.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.5.1\classmate-1.5.1.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\javax\activation\javax.activation-api\1.2.0\javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\common\hibernate-commons-annotations\5.1.2.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-5.1.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\javax\xml\bind\jaxb-api\2.3.1\jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-runtime\2.3.6\jaxb-runtime-2.3.6.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\txw2\2.3.6\txw2-2.3.6.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\com\sun\istack\istack-commons-runtime\3.0.12\istack-commons-runtime-3.0.12.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\com\sun\activation\jakarta.activation\1.2.2\jakarta.activation-1.2.2.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\org\projectlombok\lombok\1.18.24\lombok-1.18.24.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\5.3.14\spring-webmvc-5.3.14.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\5.3.20\spring-aop-5.3.20.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\5.3.20\spring-beans-5.3.20.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\5.3.20\spring-expression-5.3.20.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\5.3.14\spring-context-5.3.14.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-orm\5.3.21\spring-orm-5.3.21.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\5.3.20\spring-jdbc-5.3.20.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\5.3.20\spring-tx-5.3.20.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-jpa\2.1.5.RELEASE\spring-data-jpa-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-commons\2.7.0\spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjrt\1.9.7\aspectjrt-1.9.7.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.36\slf4j-api-1.7.36.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\javax\servlet\javax.servlet-api\4.0.1\javax.servlet-api-4.0.1.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\javax\servlet\jsp\javax.servlet.jsp-api\2.3.1\javax.servlet.jsp-api-2.3.1.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\jstl\jstl\1.2\jstl-1.2.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\mysql\mysql-connector-java\8.0.29\mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\org\thymeleaf\thymeleaf-spring5\3.0.14.RELEASE\thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\org\thymeleaf\thymeleaf\3.0.15.RELEASE\thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\org\attoparser\attoparser\2.0.5.RELEASE\attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\org\unbescape\unbescape\1.1.6.RELEASE\unbescape-1.1.6.RELEASE.jar spring_boot.Application

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.7.0)

2022-07-30 16:56:07.556  INFO 12568 --- [           main] spring_boot.Application                  : Starting Application using Java 18.0.1.1 on DESKTOP-AAKSGJM with PID 12568 (C:\java\3.1.1\target\classes started by admin in C:\java\3.1.1)
2022-07-30 16:56:07.562  INFO 12568 --- [           main] spring_boot.Application                  : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-07-30 16:56:09.291  INFO 12568 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-07-30 16:56:09.420  INFO 12568 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 111 ms. Found 2 JPA repository interfaces.
2022-07-30 16:56:11.599  INFO 12568 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2022-07-30 16:56:11.628  INFO 12568 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-07-30 16:56:11.629  INFO 12568 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.63]
2022-07-30 16:56:12.105  INFO 12568 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-07-30 16:56:12.105  INFO 12568 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 4389 ms
2022-07-30 16:56:12.189  WARN 12568 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
2022-07-30 16:56:12.192  INFO 12568 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2022-07-30 16:56:12.220  INFO 12568 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-07-30 16:56:12.250 ERROR 12568 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :
```

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class

```
Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your [application.properties](https://github.com/anatoliy19/3.1.1./blob/master/src/main/resources/application.properties#L1-L5), you need to name the datasource properties with `spring.datasource`. I.e.,

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=admin
```

You can view common data properties [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#appendix.application-properties.data).

Comment: I changed app.properties, run again,  and App failed:   No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default".
To be continued...